# Is it common to censor or soften 馬鹿 as ばしゃ?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, interjections

Unless I misheard, in an anime I am watching (安達としまむら), a character, in self-ridicule, said to themselves:

> なんだばしゃぁぁ…

I assume this is supposed to mean

> なんだ、馬鹿!?

but censored/softened.

Is this common?

If so, how would one write it? (Maybe 馬車? Not sure whether this is done in English, but in German, using a completely ordinary word that starts the same way as a curse word is a common way to curse softly.)

If not, is 馬鹿 ever censored/softened in this kind of way? Or is it not "bad" enough to need censoring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it common to censor or soften 馬鹿 as ばしゃ?

No, it is not. As you can see in [this page](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%B0%E3%81%97%E3%82%83%E3%81%81%E3%81%81%E3%81%81%E3%81%81), ばしゃあぁぁ is an original word used by the particular character in that anime, created by the author. It's not used by or known to ordinary people in real life.